# Gridview horizontal with vertical and horizontal views

Tags: android, gridview

I'm totally new in Android and I'm trying to create a new app with a special `GridView` because it's an horizontal `GridView` with vertical rows and horizontal rows, something similar to this:

[image]

The `orange row continue indefinitely` but the blue rows are loaded separately.

I'm totally lost, any idea where can I start?

Comment: Just I'm asking if I can achieve this with a Gridview? or how can I achieve it. thanks

Comment: Do you want a fixed number of items in the horizontal grid?

Comment: The horizontal row is always the same, and the vertical rows should be loaded dynamically, shouldn't it?